# How to prove the following equality about Integral closure of an ideal in regular local ring of dimension 3?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a regular local ring of dimension three and $I$ be an ideal of $R$.
Is $\bar{I^{n+1}}=I^n\bar{I}$ for all positive integer $n$? where $\bar{I}$ is integral closure of $I$.

Comment: It is known that the following question is true for regular local ring of dimension 2.